# :required => true not working

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

```
 <%= f.collection_select :categoria_pratos_id, @categorias, :id, :categoria_pt ,{} , {:required => true ,  class: "selectpicker", :label => "Categoria do Prato"}  %>
```

:required isn't working. Can someone tell me why?